# x-doc tag behavior understanding in fastify-swagger

Tags: swagger-ui, fastify

I have the following versions:

> fastify (3.20.1) and fastify-swagger(4.8.4)

I am using fastify in a Node js/JavaScript environment.

Now in my route.js, while I am specifying the fastify.route -- I am writing these two additional tags (after the `response:` section):

```
"x-doc": {
                title: 'foo1',
                category: 'NSS',
                filename: 'bar1',
            },
```

```
"my-custom-tag": {
                title: 'foo2',
                category: 'NSS',
                filename: 'bar2',
            },
```

Result:

[image]

However in the generated JSON (swagger.json or swagger.yaml), I *can* see the `x-doc` is appearing, but *not* the `my-custom-tag`.

Of course, as I did not using custom `swagger-ui`, I did not expect none of these stuffs (x-doc or my-custom-tag) to appear in the swagger html, while viewing from browser.

However I would like to know the reason behind partcularly `x-doc` to appear in resultant JSON, but not `my-custom-tag`.

*And* what I need to do if I want to make `my-custom-tag` *also* appears in resultant JSON/yaml?

Comment: Try `x-my-custom-tag`

Comment: Indeed. Thank You Very Much. It worked! So "x-" is the key here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As per comment from @Helen above, putting a "x-" makes the difference.

In swagger specification:

```
 'x-doc': {
                field1: 'property1',
                field2: 'property2',
                field3: 'property3',
            },
            'x-my-custom-tag': {
                field1: 'property1_custom',
                field2: 'property2_custom',
                field3: 'property3_custom',
            }
```

Generated JSON.

[image]